# ¿Las instancias del patrón Singleton se actualizan automáticamente cuando las recuperamos con Hibernate?

Tags: java, jsp, hibernate

Estoy desarrollando un sistema web con Java mediante JSP y servlets. Para la persistencia de datos estoy utilizando Hibernate.

Tengo una única instancia de una clase llamada Tienda, la cual a su vez tiene diversas colecciones (de usuarios, roles, artículos, etc...).

Resulta ser que cuando quiero actualizar los permisos de un rol específico, los cambios se reflejan en la base de datos, pero al momento de recuperar un usuario (por el login) desde la colección de la Tienda (siempre hago referencia a la tienda mediante `Tienda#getInstance` según el patrón Singleton), aparentemente esta colección no está actualizada, pues el usuario tiene los permisos anteriores del rol y no se percata de los nuevos.

A no ser que corra de nuevo la aplicación, el usuario no tendrá sus permisos actualizados y esto no puede ser. Ni siquiera deslogueando al usuario y haciendo que haga login otra vez se actualizan los cambios.

¿Tengo que decirle a Hibernate que cuando actualice los nuevos valores del permiso de un rol también actualice la instancia de la Tienda?

Answer (score 0):

No, es la definicion de las porpiedades de tu entidad, lo que deberias hacer es indicarle a hibernate que te obtenga todos los objetos relacionados a tienda y si no tienen cambios, actualizar tienda pero con los objetos seteados, espero haberme explicado